# Unable to submit the form using Resource Routing

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, routes

I'm a newbie so my apologies if this is just dumb question.I just started laravel version 4.2. I just stuck with a routing error whenever I try to submit my form I get the following error.
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::post()
here is the snip of routes.php

[image: Route]

This is the view for the form and form action is being set to abc(controller) where method name is @store

[image: View]

Here is the controller named abc where I declared my store function to store the user values into database.

[image: Controller]

Php artisan Route Command

[image]

Any help would be more appreciated. thanks

Comment: edit the `store()` method as `public function store()
 {
  return "ok";
 }` and check "ok" prints after submit.

Comment: yup done the job thanks

Comment: In laravel, we use ::get() to retrieve all input from the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be corrected by simply change the following lines:

```
$guest->user = Input::post('user')
$guest->password = Hash::make(Input::post('password'));
```

to

```
$guest->user = Input::get('user')
$guest->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
```

Basically `Input::post` is not the method you use to access POST variables. `Input::get` get fetch any variable from current request. (More like `$_REQUEST`).